# run linux command from java

Tags: java, linux, jar

i tried to run linux command from **jar file**, but i always get this error:

java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ls": error=13, Permission denied.

here is my code:

```
String s;
    Process p;
    String cmd= "ls";

    try {
        Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
        p = run.exec(cmd);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println("line: " + s);
        }

        p.waitFor();
        System.out.println ("exit: " + p.exitValue());
        p.destroy();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

thanks for your time.

**UPDATE**:
For me, my solution is: i had to reinstall my OS and JDK, everything is working now.

Comment: Sounds like you have a file called `ls` that's not an executable program. Try changing the command to `"/bin/ls"`

Comment: same error: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/bin/ls": error=13, Permission denied

Comment: Try `String cmd= "ls -l";`

Comment: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ls": error=13, Permission denied

Comment: Run the terminal from the folder where jar is present. To give all the permissions (read, write & execute) -> `chmod -R 777 /folder`. Then execute the jar

Comment: still same error

Comment: i have installed eclipse, created new class with main method, when i run it i get:

Cannot run program "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-13.0.2/bin/java" (in directory "/root/eclipse-workspace/hello"): error=13, Permission denied

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash thank you for your response, well i had to reinstall my os and jdk, now everthing is working fine.

Comment: thank you guys for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you are familiar with `vi`. If not, ignore the 3rd command given below and just copy `Main.java` file to `/Users/your-user-directory/`

```
cd ~
pwd
vi Main.java
javac Main.java
java Main
```

**Main.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s;
        Process p;
        String cmd = "ls";

        try {
            Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
            p = run.exec(cmd);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("line: " + s);
            }

            p.waitFor();
            System.out.println("exit: " + p.exitValue());
            p.destroy();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```